# How to declare a variable as char* const*?

Tags: c++, c, char, declaration

I have a bluez header file `get_opt.h` where `argv` is an argument:

```
 extern int getopt_long (int ___argc, char *__getopt_argv_const *___argv,.....
```

which requires `char* const*` for `argv`. Because the unit is called from a different file I was trying to emulate `argv` but whatever permutation of declaring `char`, `const` and `*` is used I get unqualified-id or the compiler moans about not converting to `char* const*`. I can get `const char *` easily, of course. `char const * argv = "0";` compiles OK in Netbeans with C++14 but

```
char * const * argv = "0";
```

produces

> "error: cannot convert 'const char *' to 'char * const *'" in initialisation (sic).

How do you declare `char* const*` or am I mixing C with C++ so I'm up the wrong tree?

Comment: You can declare a variable as `char* const*` by declaring it as `char* const*`. It is hard to determine why this did not work for your without a [mre] and the error message (copy-pasted, not interpreted).

Comment: Pick the example that you feel was closest to correct, and the first error reported. Maybe use a horizontal rule (`---` on a line by itself) and provide a second example (and its first error message) as a footnote, if this does not become distractingly long.

Comment: @JaMiT Understand about no reproducible example but there were/are so many. char * const * did not work in this situation. char const * argv = "0";  compiles OK in Netbeans with C++14 but char * const * produces error: cannot convert 'const char *' to 'char * const *' in initialisation (sic)

Comment: Good, that's an example. Please add it to your question. Also, you might want to notice how you can remove the call to `getopt_long()` from that example while retaining the error (it's motivation for your declaration, but not the source of your issue). If you think about your presentation enough, you might realize that your question is not how to *declare* a `char* const*` but how to *initialize* it.

Comment: Due to arrays decaying to a pointer, you could declare an array of pointers (`char* const argv[]`) instead of a pointer to pointer (`char* const * argv`). See _The 1D array of pointers way_ portion of [A: 2D Pointer initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6465638) for how to initialize such a beast. *Beware:* given your setup, the "2D array way" from that answer is not an option. *Reminder:* The last pointer in the argument vector is null; `argv[argc] == nullptr` when those values are provided by the system to `main()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Credit @JaMiT above

[I don't know how to accept a commment]

> Also, you might want to notice how you can remove the call to `getopt_long()` from that example while retaining the error (it's motivation for your declaration, but not the source of your issue). If you think about your presentation enough, you might realize that your question is not how to declare a `char* const*` but how to initialize it. Due to arrays decaying to a pointer, you could declare an array of pointers (`char* const argv[]`) instead of a pointer to pointer (`char* const * argv`). See The 1D array of pointers way portion of A: 2D Pointer initialization for how to initialize such a beast. Beware: given your setup, the "2D array way" from that answer is not an option. Reminder: The last pointer in the argument vector is null; `argv[argc] == nullptr` when those values are provided by the system to `main()`.

Answer (score 2):

Let's review the pointer declarations:

```
char *             -- mutable pointer to mutable data.  
char const *       -- mutable pointer to constant data.  
char       * const -- constant pointer to mutable data.  
char const * const -- constant pointer to constant data.
```

Read pointer declarations from right to left.

Looking at the descriptions, which kind of pointer do you want?

Comment: OP thinks that he has to change the type of main function parameters to match the function one :)

Comment: @Thomas Saw that before. Clear and helpful thank you but it didn't work in this situation.

Answer (score 1):

> Because void main(void) is in a different file I was trying to emulate
> argv

`void main(void)` is not the correct main function declaration. The `main` function has to have `int` return value.

Simply change the `void main(void)` to `int main(int argc, char **argv)` in that "other" file.

It does not require `char const *` to be passed to. Do not change the type of the `main` function arguments.

```
int getopt_long (int ___argc, char * const *___argv);

int main(int argc, char **argv) 
{
    printf("%d\n", getopt_long(argc, argv));
}
```

Both language compile fine:
https://godbolt.org/z/5To5T931j